# React - use Dependencies in useEffect without trigger the effect itself when the Dependency change

Tags: reactjs

I have a react state

`const [list, setList] = useState([])`

and a react effect that is triggered when the list is modified, and do some work with the first element in the list:

```
useEffect( () => {
  if(list.length <= 0) return

  //Do something with the first element of the list

  //Remove first element of the list

}, [list])
```

In this way, the effect trigger itself `n` times where `n` is the number of the element in the list.

Then i have another method in my component that insert elements in the list with the `setList()` method, let's call it

```
insertElemInList = () => {
  //insert one or more elements in list
}
```

when `insertElemInList` is called, the useEffect trigger and start working for `n` times.
I don't know how many times the `insertElemInList()` is called, and how many elements is inserted every time, since this method is called after some actions of the user on the page.
So if an user call the `insertElemInList()` two or more times, before the last iteration of the effect is finished, then the effect trigger in the wrong way, in fact it will activate due to the change of state given by `insertElemInList`, but also by itself, resulting in more iterations and wrong behaviour.

So i'm trying to figure out how to use something inside the effect that doesn't trigger the effect itself, but can be used correctly.
for example I was thinking of modifying the effect and the state adding

`const [semWait, setSem] = useState(1)`

and then, continue to update the `list` state with the `insertElemInList()` method, but now:

```
useEffect( () => {  

 let doSomething = () => {

  if(list.length < 0) return

  //Do Something with the first element of the list

  //Remove first element from the list

  if(list.length > 0) doSomething()
 }

 doSomething()

 setSem(1)

}, [semWait])

insertElemInList = () => {
  //insert one or more elements in list

  if(semWait == 1) setSem(0)
}
```

the above code is just an example of how I can solve the problem, I don't think it is the best solution and I gave you this example just to make you understand what I would like to do.
however, as you can see in this way I could add as many value as i want to my state whith `insertElemInList()` ​​and trigger the effect only if it is not already active (in other word, only if the semaphore is reset by the effect itself). However, I know it's not a good thing to use a state in the effect, without including it in dependencies, and if i add the state `list` as dependency of the `useEffect` the problem return.

the problem is that I can't figure out how to use a value inside useEffect without including it in the dependency

EDIT:
sorry for the late reply, i tried to implement this code on my own but there are workflow problems in my work, i'll try to explain the problems:

the code is a snippet to download some file from an API, the user on the site have a list of files to download, he can click on the files to download them as many times as he wants. my intent is to create a request queue, so as not to send too many requests to the server.

the code below show my work, i've inserted some comments to let you figure out how my code should work:

```
const [queue, setQueue] = useState({
  "op_name": "NO_OP"
})

//file download function
let requestFileDownload = (fileId) => {

  /*
  This function construct the object to put in queue state and call the method 'insertInQueue'
  */

  let workState = appState

  insertInQueue({
    "op_name": "DOWNLOAD_FILE",
    "file_id": fileId,
    "username": workState.user.username,
    "token": workState.user.token
  })
}


//Function insertInQueue to insert an element in the queue
let insertInQueue = (objQueue) => {
    
  //Some control to check if the object passed exist, and have valid fields
  if (!objQueue || !objQueue.op_name || objQueue.op_name === "NO_OP") return //nothing to insert in queue

  //calling method to insert in timeline div, this work only whith front-end dom elements (full synchronous)
  insertElemInTimeline(objQueue.op_name)

    //setting timeout in which try to insert the object passed in queue
  setTimeout(function run() {
    let workQueue = queue //gettind queue object
    if (workQueue && workQueue.op_name === "NO_OP") {
        /*
      if queue exist and the op_name is "NO_OP", this mean that the previus operations on the queue
      is finished, so we can start this operation
      */
      setQueue(objQueue) //set the queue with the object passed as paramether to trigger the effect
      return;
    }

    // if the queue op_name was != "NO_OP" call the function again for retry to insert in 1 second
    setTimeout(run, 1000)
  }, 0)
}



//Effect triggered when queue object change
useEffect(() => {

  if (queue.op_name === "NO_OP") return //no operation to do

    //Effective file download
  let downloadFileEffect = async () => {

    let objQueue = queue //getting queue state

        //Two functions to download the element by calling backend api
    let downloadFileResponse = await downloadFile(objQueue.file_id, objQueue.username, objQueue.token)
    download(downloadFileResponse.data, downloadFileResponse.headers['x-suggested-filename'])

        //after the method have completed, i can set a new state for the queue with "op_name": "NO_OP"
    let appoStateQueue = {
      "op_name": "NO_OP"
    }
    setQueue(appoStateQueue)

        //method for remove the element from the dom
    removeElemFromTimeline()
  }

    //calling function to trigger the donwload.
  downloadFileEffect()

}, [queue])
```

now the problem is, that when i try to reset the queue state in the effect, when i call:

```
let appoStateQueue = {
      "op_name": "NO_OP"
    }
    setQueue(appoStateQueue)
```

the queue is not resetted in the case the user have clicked two download one after the first is running.
In fact the queue stops with the first object inserted in it, and is not reset by the effect, so the second download never starts, because it sees forever the queue occupied by the first download.

In case user click one download, then wait for the download, and only then click the second, then there's no problem, and the queue is resetted correctly by the effect

Answer (score 0):

First, `useEffect` doesn't run for "trigger itself `n` times where `n` is the number of the element in the list". `useEffect` will run every time `list` changes in length or resides in a different memory space than it did in a previous render. This is how "shallow" comparison works with javascript objects in react. Your main issue is that you are changing your dependency from within the effect. This means that while the effect runs, it updates the dependency and forces it to run again and again and again...memory leak!

Your solution *might* work, but as you stated is not best practice. A better solution (imo) would be to allow for a "parsedList" state that can be the end result of parsing the list. Let the source of truth with the list only be impacted by the client interaction. You monitor these changes and change your `parsedList` based on these changes.

Comment: ok, so you mean to add another `parsedList` state with which the effect works and make sure that only the client goes to modify the `list` state? but when you say "You monitor these changes..." do you mean for example a setInterval in wich i control when the parsedList is empty and only then (so, only when the effect is done) i move the elements from `list` to `parsedList`?

Comment: If you post more of your actual code so I can see what you're doing, I can give you a more precise example. For now, I don't really know what exactly you are attempting to do with the list or what the use case is.